# blackens the screen

Tags: screen, browser

I have a problem I can not solve. Use xubuntu 14.04 on a PC Acer 2920Z with 2 gb of ram. Now the question is simple, when I use chrome or chromium, it makes no difference after a few seconds I blackens the screen and the computer becomes unusable. I am forced to restart.As with any other browser is not happening to me. Someone who can suggest solutions? Thank you so much for those who want to give me aid is involved.

Comment: I keep reading stuff like this.  Though I am still using 12.04, I promise, after about January 2nd or so, I'm going to install/upgrade to (or both) to 14.04 so I can witness the problem that so many people seem to be having.  Since I have about THIRTY installations on portable media, even if I only upgrade a couple of them, it won't take me long to try them on dozens of different PCs and see which hardware combinations seem to cause instability.  If I can make the solution easy, trust that I will post the easy solution.  At this time however, just reading about it is causing me great anxiety.

Comment: Thank you for reading this post. You can tell that the problem, at least for me, was born at a time when use youtube or any other video player within the Google browser. And the best that the screen can not be seen because it is all black but the audio I confirm that everything works, but inexplicably blackens the screen ..... Go figure!?!?!?!

Answer (score 0):

After you replied to my comment I decided to do a google search and found a repetition of your complaint by others and regarding several versions of Ubuntu.  After some more searching, I found this result which indicates the problem was solved.  Unfortunately I'm too busy to try to interpret what actually worked.  Please read this thread and see if it applies to your problem and if so, please let me know.  I admit to being curious myself.

http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f64/solved-system-freezing-continuously-while-running-chrome-840698.html